# Array model binding in Angular and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm working on web application using Angular 2 + Asp.net Core stack and trying to create objects filtering now.

So I need this model to be sent to the server side:

```
export class FilterModel {
    public params: string[];
}
```

And I create this URL for the request like this:

> api/myctrl/mymethod?params=IJk0Kc60EeacVZTegG5OnA,LgE2TM60EeacVZTegG5OnA

On the server side I have model class like this:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public IList<string> Params { get; set; }
}
```

and controller like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyctrlController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<AnotherModel> Params(FilterModel filter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I expect to see inside the list filter.Params two items "IJk0Kc60EeacVZTegG5OnA" and "LgE2TM60EeacVZTegG5OnA" but I get single "IJk0Kc60EeacVZTegG5OnA,LgE2TM60EeacVZTegG5OnA"

What should I do to get right model binding? Can I customise model binding somehow or may be I should use diferent url to make thing work right way?